# Plane with Principled BSD with image not enough contrast

Tags: texturing, uv

I use an image with black letters and white background as the texture on a plane.

[image]

But the contrast after rendering is very bad. How can I increase the contrast? Or is it possible withput external light source to make the white part of the texture gloom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because of the Color Management, in the Render setting. You have to change it from "Filmic" to "Standard".

Filmic :
[image]

Standard :
[image]

By default Blender uses the "Filmic" color management, which handles better colors with high values of light.
When working with "true colors" (ex : for a 2D project with precise HEX values), you have to set the color management to "Standard".

If you want to know more, Chris Brejon got you covered : https://chrisbrejon.com/cg-cinematography/chapter-1-color-management/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your lighting is not strong enough and you need to add a light. Or you can use an *Emission* node instead of a *Diffuse*, or if you use a *Principled BSDF*, plug your image into the *Emission* input, and play with the *Emission Strngth* value: at a rate of 1 you'll see the text as it is and you won't need any light. At a higher rate the material will get brighter and the text will tend to fade out.

[image]